# zip all list from dictionary

Tags: c#, .net, zip

I have a dictionary with list of values

Lists are dynamic added on runtime. In c# how can I Zip all the list from dictionary?

Sample:

```
Dictionary<string, List<string>> MyDictionary = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();

List<int> firstlist= new List<string>();

firstlist.Add("one");

firstlist.Add("two");

firstlist.Add("three");

firstlist.Add("four");

List<int> secondlist= new List<int>();

secondlist.Add(1);

secondlist.Add(2);

secondlist.Add(3);

secondlist.Add(4);

MyDictionary.Add("Words", firstlist);
MyDictionary.Add("Number", secondlist);
```

I want to zip all the list from mydictionary so the result would be:

```
one       1
two       2
three     3
four      4
```

Comment: Try using googlw and give plwase more detalis

Comment: Do you get any error message with the code you are showing?

Comment: Do you mean that you want all the lists in the `Dictionary` to be added to the same list with the `Enumerable.Zip` function?

Comment: what should the result look like?

Comment: sorry I just updated my post

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given a `Dictionary` of `List`s:

```
var d = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>()
{
    {"first",  new List<string>() {"one", "two", "three"}},
    {"second", new List<string>() {"1",   "2",   "3"}}, 
    {"third",  new List<string>() {"A",   "B",   "C"}}
};
```

you could use this generic method:

```
IEnumerable<TResult> ZipIt<TSource, TResult>(IEnumerable<IEnumerable<TSource>> collection, 
                                            Func<IEnumerable<TSource>, TResult> resultSelector)
{
    var enumerators = collection.Select(c => c.GetEnumerator()).ToList();
    while (enumerators.All(e => e.MoveNext()))
    {
        yield return resultSelector(enumerators.Select(e => (TSource)e.Current).ToList());
    }
}
```

to zip all lists within this dictionary, for example like this:

```
var result = ZipIt(d.Values, xs => String.Join(", ", xs)).ToList();
```

`result` is now

[image]

Note that this method lets you choose how to combine the values; in my example I just create a `,`-separated string. You could also just use something else.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var dictionary = firstlist.Zip(secondlist, (value, key) => new { value, key })
                         .ToDictionary(x => x.key, x => x.value);
```

Take a look at this example from the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698.aspx):

```
 int[] numbers = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
 string[] words = { "one", "two", "three" };

 var numbersAndWords = numbers.Zip(words, (first, second) => first + " " + second);

 foreach (var item in numbersAndWords)
     Console.WriteLine(item);

 // This code produces the following output: 
 // 1 one 
 // 2 two 
 // 3 three
```

EDIT:

To access the lists in the dictionary use:

```
(List<string>)MyDictionary["words"];
(List<int>)MyDictionary["numbers"];
```

For example:

```
List<string> words = (List<string>)MyDictionary["words"];
List<int> numbers = (List<int>)MyDictionary["numbers"];
for (int i = 0; i < words.Count; i++) // Loop through List with for
{
    Console.WriteLine(words[i] + numbers [i]);
}
```

Comment: He wants the opposite, I believe. He wants his all lists FROM the dictionary to be zipped, rather than zip two lists to a dictionary.

Comment: Yes I want to zip all the list from my dictionary, since the list are dynamic and added during runtime

Comment: Whats the output you wish to have? im a bit confused now

Comment: I updated my post with the sample output, sorry to keep you confused

Answer (score 0):

Let's work backwards from the [documetation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698.aspx) example:

```
    int[] numbers = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    string[] words = { "one", "two", "three" };

    var numbersAndWords = numbers.Zip(words, (first, second) => first +
         " " + second);

    foreach (var item in numbersAndWords)
        Console.WriteLine(item);

    // This code produces the following output: 

    // 1 one 
    // 2 two 
    // 3 three
```

So then using your dictionary from above it would be:

```
    var numbersAndWords = MyDictionary["Words"]
        .Zip(MyDictionary["Number"], (first, second) => first + "\t" + second);

    foreach (var item in numbersAndWords)
        Console.WriteLine(item);

    // This code produces the following output: 

    // one       1
    // two       2
    // three     3
    // four      4
```

Comment: very close, but the keys in dictionary is also dynamic, I mean it can have many keys not limited to two.